# How do I flattening a MultiIndex column

Tags: pandas, dataframe

Here's my data

```
              customer_id   value
var_name                    Value_1     Value_2 
0             1             70          80
```

I want to make it

```
var_name      customer_id   Value_1     Value_2 
0             1             70          80
```

what I did is `df.columns  = ['customer_id',  'Value_1', 'Value_2']` but this is to prone to mistake since I had hundreds of columns

How suppose I do this?

Comment: Maybe is possible prevent it, how is your code for this `MultiIndex` ?

Comment: This is how I got the `MultiIndex` the code is
`df= data.pivot_table(index=['customer_id'], columns='var_name', fill_value=0 , aggfunc='max').reset_index()`

Comment: Do `index='customer_id'` instead

Comment: @coldspeed the use of list and a string for index appears all the time. Shouldn't there be a dupe target. Its becoming a common question.

Comment: @Dark yeah but I cba to find it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You always get `MultiIndex`, because no parameter `values` with one value:

```
df = data.pivot_table(index='customer_id', 
                      columns='var_name', 
                      fill_value=0, 
                      aggfunc='max')

#columns names of first level  are not removed 
df.columns = df.columns.map('_'.join)
#first level removed, but possible duplicated columns names, so not recommended
#df.columns = df.columns.droplevel(0)

df = df.reset_index()
```

If scalar in `value` (processes one column only):

```
df = data.pivot_table(index='customer_id', 
                      columns='var_name', 
                     fill_value=0, 
                     values='age',
                     aggfunc='max')
```

Comment: actually I have mutilple index `['customer_id', 'device_id', 'age', 'created_at'], still checking is that works on my case